# Why does my jquery code works inside a page locally but not from masterpage?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms, master-pages

I have been working on a mini website which mainly uses jquery, ajax and a bit of c# code. It's working. Scripts are working too but when I added a web form with master page then jquery and bootstrap part stopped working.

I guess links are not getting resolved in masterpage. In general, it throws this error upon clicking an image inside the repeater:

```
 ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.displayStory (frmHome.aspx:225)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (frmHome.aspx:56)
```

but the same code works correctly when used outside master page such as inside the page locally.

Masterpage code:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Master.master.cs" Inherits="HimHer.Master" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title></title>
    <link runat="server" href="~/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" id="btncollapse" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarcollapse">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" target="_self" href="../Pages/frmMain.aspx">HerHim</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="navbarcollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li class="Active"><a href="../Pages/frmMain.aspx">home</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">About<span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="me.html" target="_blank">Me</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="her.html" target="_blank">Her</a></li>
                                    <li></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Our Story</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>

            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolderPageContents" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            <footer class="footer">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <a class="footer" href="#" target="_blank">Facebook</a>
                            <a class="footer" href="#" target="_blank">Quora</a>
                            <a class="footer" href="#" target="_blank">Twitter</a>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </footer>

            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolderScripts" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
    </form>

   <%-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>--%>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%# ResolveUrl("~/assets/js/jquery.min.js") %>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%# ResolveUrl("~/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js") %>" ></script>



</body>
</html>
```

Webform code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="frmHome.aspx.cs" Inherits="HimHer.frmHome" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderPageContents" runat="server">
    <div class="container-fluid">
            <asp:Repeater ID="rptrImages" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">                
                            <input type="hidden" id="txtID" value='<%#Eval("ID")%>' />
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgButtonStory"  OnClientClick='displayStory.call(this);return false;' runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "../assets/UploadedImages/"+ Eval("Image") %>' 
                             CssClass="img-responsive img-rounded" />
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>     

            <!-- Modal -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
            <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">

                    <!-- Modal content-->
                    <div class="modal-content" style="opacity: 0.8 !important;">
                        <div class="modal-body">

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderScripts" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">



        function displayStory()
        {

            var txtIDValue = $(this).prev('input[id$=txtID]').val();

            var id = txtIDValue;

            //alert(id);

            $.ajax
            ({
                url: 'http://localhost:11552/Stories/' + id,
                type: 'GET',
                contentType: "application/json; charset= utf-8",
                success: function (results) {

                    //alert(results);
                    $('.modal-body').html(results);
                    $('#myModal').modal('show');


                }

            });

        }
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

my project structure:

[image]

Update:

A rendered HTML code of the page causing the issue.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="gr__localhost"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><title>

</title><link href="../assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script type="text/javascript" src=""></script>


</head>
<body data-gr-c-s-loaded="true">
    <form method="post" action="frmHome.aspx" id="form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="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">
</div>

<div class="aspNetHidden">

    <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="2B31F3C9">
    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="+4kAw2IrsWz1m1nU74L+u2I9cHXcJOAQuYsf4l1MQyRrF/4wYcihWtHQ1BBj3mQrNiF7yOuzdAS5+vE+nDw55C90DsYVC8pcHL60OOwpvAnP04gbOOcANriXf3j+JzsUcocLqKcdW4ZhjcHb1nkpN/laTaUPGwO7HwLW9nFlLC0uZHtQj55JRfSL3jIasd6PBKgarQqvmlXJs/OQw2MtPEDXlcdTb6JUs1tiCMffOLkjn5ZPxwni23QdMtK5NiOUhZMqSrL04js0MCX4QQBK0LwiW/zBBvPEzxc+TMokbkRhE4vGrblEwfSCaiHBgb9vgZ13xY+G6Og0JrK9G0xthZuhaUNHFWJfw1w4CfSxaeyk1Glohia4powzK5CHyFBLMkbdlkMCUpdCEuP3a64CaONlyL0TVHOjGyZWnm79+a0=">
</div>
        <div>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" id="btncollapse" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarcollapse">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" target="_self" href="../Pages/frmMain.aspx">HerHim</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="navbarcollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li class="Active"><a href="../Pages/frmMain.aspx">home</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">About<span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="me.html" target="_blank">Me</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="her.html" target="_blank">Her</a></li>
                                    <li></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Our Story</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>


    <div class="container-fluid">


                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">                
                            <input type="hidden" id="txtID" value="41">
                            <input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderPageContents$rptrImages$ctl00$imgButtonStory" id="ContentPlaceHolderPageContents_rptrImages_imgButtonStory_0" class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="../assets/UploadedImages/Einstein-fake-quote.png" onclick="displayStory.call(this);return false;">
                        </div>

                    </div>


                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">                
                            <input type="hidden" id="txtID" value="42">
                            <input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderPageContents$rptrImages$ctl01$imgButtonStory" id="ContentPlaceHolderPageContents_rptrImages_imgButtonStory_1" class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="../assets/UploadedImages/Einstein-fake-quote.png" onclick="displayStory.call(this);return false;">
                        </div>

                    </div>


                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">                
                            <input type="hidden" id="txtID" value="43">
                            <input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderPageContents$rptrImages$ctl02$imgButtonStory" id="ContentPlaceHolderPageContents_rptrImages_imgButtonStory_2" class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="../assets/UploadedImages/Einstein-fake-quote.png" onclick="displayStory.call(this);return false;">
                        </div>

                    </div>


                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">                
                            <input type="hidden" id="txtID" value="44">
                            <input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderPageContents$rptrImages$ctl03$imgButtonStory" id="ContentPlaceHolderPageContents_rptrImages_imgButtonStory_3" class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="../assets/UploadedImages/Einstein-fake-quote.png" onclick="displayStory.call(this);return false;">
                        </div>

                    </div>


                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">                
                            <input type="hidden" id="txtID" value="45">
                            <input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderPageContents$rptrImages$ctl04$imgButtonStory" id="ContentPlaceHolderPageContents_rptrImages_imgButtonStory_4" class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="../assets/UploadedImages/Einstein-fake-quote.png" onclick="displayStory.call(this);return false;">
                        </div>

                    </div>


                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">                
                            <input type="hidden" id="txtID" value="46">
                            <input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderPageContents$rptrImages$ctl05$imgButtonStory" id="ContentPlaceHolderPageContents_rptrImages_imgButtonStory_5" class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="../assets/UploadedImages/Einstein-fake-quote.png" onclick="displayStory.call(this);return false;">
                        </div>

                    </div>


                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">                
                            <input type="hidden" id="txtID" value="47">
                            <input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderPageContents$rptrImages$ctl06$imgButtonStory" id="ContentPlaceHolderPageContents_rptrImages_imgButtonStory_6" class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="../assets/UploadedImages/Einstein-fake-quote.png" onclick="displayStory.call(this);return false;">
                        </div>

                    </div>


                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">                
                            <input type="hidden" id="txtID" value="48">
                            <input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderPageContents$rptrImages$ctl07$imgButtonStory" id="ContentPlaceHolderPageContents_rptrImages_imgButtonStory_7" class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="../assets/UploadedImages/Einstein-fake-quote.png" onclick="displayStory.call(this);return false;">
                        </div>

                    </div>


                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">                
                            <input type="hidden" id="txtID" value="49">
                            <input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderPageContents$rptrImages$ctl08$imgButtonStory" id="ContentPlaceHolderPageContents_rptrImages_imgButtonStory_8" class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="../assets/UploadedImages/21272618_1456062094508797_3312300394502505144_n.jpg" onclick="displayStory.call(this);return false;">
                        </div>

                    </div>


                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">                
                            <input type="hidden" id="txtID" value="50">
                            <input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderPageContents$rptrImages$ctl09$imgButtonStory" id="ContentPlaceHolderPageContents_rptrImages_imgButtonStory_9" class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="../assets/UploadedImages/21272618_1456062094508797_3312300394502505144_n.jpg" onclick="displayStory.call(this);return false;">
                        </div>

                    </div>


                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">                
                            <input type="hidden" id="txtID" value="51">
                            <input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderPageContents$rptrImages$ctl10$imgButtonStory" id="ContentPlaceHolderPageContents_rptrImages_imgButtonStory_10" class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="../assets/UploadedImages/21314846_1421821901219588_1436933803217390559_n.jpg" onclick="displayStory.call(this);return false;">
                        </div>

                    </div>


                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">                
                            <input type="hidden" id="txtID" value="52">
                            <input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderPageContents$rptrImages$ctl11$imgButtonStory" id="ContentPlaceHolderPageContents_rptrImages_imgButtonStory_11" class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="../assets/UploadedImages/bb.jpg" onclick="displayStory.call(this);return false;">
                        </div>

                    </div>


                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">                
                            <input type="hidden" id="txtID" value="53">
                            <input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderPageContents$rptrImages$ctl12$imgButtonStory" id="ContentPlaceHolderPageContents_rptrImages_imgButtonStory_12" class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="../assets/UploadedImages/21314588_1823996714284713_1288102688851100305_n.jpg" onclick="displayStory.call(this);return false;">
                        </div>

                    </div>


                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">                
                            <input type="hidden" id="txtID" value="54">
                            <input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderPageContents$rptrImages$ctl13$imgButtonStory" id="ContentPlaceHolderPageContents_rptrImages_imgButtonStory_13" class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="../assets/UploadedImages/21314588_1823996714284713_1288102688851100305_n.jpg" onclick="displayStory.call(this);return false;">
                        </div>

                    </div>


                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">                
                            <input type="hidden" id="txtID" value="55">
                            <input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderPageContents$rptrImages$ctl14$imgButtonStory" id="ContentPlaceHolderPageContents_rptrImages_imgButtonStory_14" class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="../assets/UploadedImages/21314846_1421821901219588_1436933803217390559_n.jpg" onclick="displayStory.call(this);return false;">
                        </div>

                    </div>


            <!-- Modal -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
            <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">

                    <!-- Modal content-->
                    <div class="modal-content" style="opacity: 0.8 !important;">
                        <div class="modal-body">

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

            <footer class="footer">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <a class="footer" href="#" target="_blank">Facebook</a>
                            <a class="footer" href="#" target="_blank">Quora</a>
                            <a class="footer" href="#" target="_blank">Twitter</a>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </footer>


    <script type="text/javascript">



        function displayStory()
        {

            var txtIDValue = $(this).prev('input[id$=txtID]').val();

            var id = txtIDValue;

            //alert(id);

            $.ajax
            ({
                url: 'http://localhost:11552/Stories/' + id,
                type: 'GET',
                contentType: "application/json; charset= utf-8",
                success: function (results) {

                    //alert(results);
                    $('.modal-body').html(results);
                    $('#myModal').modal('show');


                }

            });

        }
    </script>

        </div>
    </form>



    <script type="text/javascript" src=""></script>





</body></html>
```

Comment: Please update your post with the HTML (View Source from the web browser) off the page that has the issue. We will be able to point out your mistake very quickly.

Comment: @mjwills: updated, check the code

Comment: The short answer is you can't use `$` **above** where jquery is loaded. In the HTML you have included, jquery does not appear to be loaded **at all**. _There is no `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">` in that HTML._

Comment: @mjwills: WHat's the solution then ?

Comment: I suspect you should add it?

Comment: @mjwills: I have copied the code inside online jquery.min.js and put it into the js file inside the assets and that online code has been commented long ago

Comment: but I tried with this too and not working

Comment: @mjwills I tried with that too but not working

Answer (score 1):

I saw that you have included jquery.min.js file in your footer in master page. So it will load at last when any page renders.

I know its good practice to load JS files in footer but just for jquery to work, it must be included before your own jquery script get loaded.

It worked within your custom pages because they get loaded when the master view will be loaded. But not with master view file.

Conclusion: Move your jquery include tag in `<head>` tags. This one:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="<%# ResolveUrl("~/assets/js/jquery.min.js") %>"></script>`

Comment: hey @Stacky, if the answer solved your problem, can you accept it please?

Comment: let me check bhai

Comment: You need to move bootstrap.js to top like jquery.min.js because these both are needed to render the page with bootstrap and you js code.

Comment: any solution to this ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies but later I figured it out. You just need to put **../** not resolve or **~** sign.

```
  <script src="../assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```